# how could I automate an installer with Python?

Tags: python, installation, stdout, stdin, silent-installer

So we have our software product, which I'm currently working on a way to automate its installation. The way it will be done is:

- I have a `config.cfg` file, which has all the information about `Apache`, `Tomcat` and `MySQL's` user and password, as well as port numbers.
- I use `ConfigParser` to have that information available.

The installer script is iterative: you execute it like `sudo foo.run` and it prompts the command line so the person doing the installation can enter the inputs mentioned above. For example:

```
Apache user: **[foo]** 
Apache password: **[bar]**
```

and after that information is entered, the installer actually installs the product. However, I want to automate the full process, including inputting those informations using `Python`.

So far I came with this:

```
  1 from subprocess import Popen, call, PIPE, STDOUT
  2 import errno
  3 import os
  4 fname = "/home/ec2-user/foo.run"
  5 os.chmod(fname, 0777) # make it executable
  6 cmd = "sudo %s" % fname
  7 print cmd
  9 p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
 10           stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
 11 # now is actually the missing part ... reading from the stdout and writing
 12 # to stdin ... how could I accomplish that? Is there a easier way of doing it?
 13 p.wait()
```

So I'm having a little trouble designing how that `stdin` / `stdout` part would work ...
I need a `while` loop to read from it until `stdout` is empty, and then I would inject the data contained in `ConfigParser`.
Could someone please give an example how that could be done? Is there any other easier way of doing it? I'm open to any suggestions ... A first step for me could be doing a manual installer from python, using `Python's` `p.stdin.write()` to give the informations to the installer.

Comment: Use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) instead of subprocess to run the program. Its job is to run interactive command line programs from python and the reference has examples you can use to make it go.

Comment: seems odd to have an installer that demands manual input and then to have to do various twisty stuff to automatically provide that manual input.  The place I work has python based products too.  They install automatically and use shell scripts to configure apache, mysql etc

Comment: You should use pexpect, or even better just rethink your `foo.run` installer to get those parameters directly from your config file.